# Problema con subida de archivo nodejs usando formidable

Tags: json, nodejs

```
//probando subida de imagen

router.post('/uploadImage', (request, response, next) => {
    let formidable = require('formidable');
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.uploadDir = "../imagenes/";
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
    form.multiples = true;

    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {

        if (err) {
            response.json({
                message: 'error al subir la imagen',
                data: {}
            });
        }

        var  arrayOfFiles = files[""];

        if (arrayOfFiles.length > 0) {
            var fileNames = [];
            arrayOfFiles.forEach((eachFile) => {
                fileNames.push(eachFile.path)
            });

            response.json({
                message: 'imagen subida correctamente !!',
                //data = fileNames,
                //numImagenes = fileNames.length
            })
        }

        else {
            response.json({
                message: 'No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ',
                data: {},
               // numImagenes: 0
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Salida del error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**No entiendo ese error es muy raro que me diga que no conoce una propiedad tan común como la de un 'length' de un array, ¿alguien sabe decirme a que se debe este extraño error?**

---

> Con la adaptacion me devuelve que esta vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: para que no me diese erro estas dos variables las he tenido que inicializar de la siguiente forma, no se si sera correcto =

```
  const data = []; //variable para la respuesta al Front
    const  filesPath = '' //variable donde guardaremos todos los path de los archivos subidos
```

El codigo adaptado usado actualmente :

```
router.post('/uploadImage', (request, response) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    const address = path.dirname(__filename).split('/')
    address.pop()

    form.uploadDir = "../imagenes/";
    form.keepExtensions = true; //mantener las extensiones
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
    form.multiples = true; //multiples archivos

    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {

        var data = []; //variable para la respuesta al Front
        var  filesPath = '' //variable donde guardaremos todos los path de los archivos subidos

        if (err) {
            response.json ( {
                message: 'error al subir la imagen',
                data: []
            })
        }

        if (files.length > 0) {
            filesPath = files.map(file => file.path); //Recorremos el array de objetos y devolvemos uno nuevo con solo los path de los archivos subidos.
            //se puede devolver los nombres haciendo esto files.map(file => file.name)
            response.json ( {
                message: 'imagen subida correctamente !!',
                data : filesPath,
                numImagenes : filesPath.length
            })
        } else {
            response.json ( {
                message: 'No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ',
                data: [],
                numImagenes: 0
            })
        }
    })

    response.json(data)
})
```

Comment: según veo en tu código el error esta en esta declaración `var  arrayOfFiles = files[""];`, esto hace que la variable 'arrayOfFiles' sea 'undefined' y al consultar la propiedad 'length' no existe, ese es el motivo del error.

Comment: y que tendria que ponerle en el array para que aceptara la propiedad 'length?'

Comment: Según tu código, tendría que ser un array ya que luego utilizas el método 'forEach' para recorrerlo. Aunque no tengo muy claro para qué realizas eso, realmente que necesitas hacer?

Comment: a ver es una funcion de mi api que quiero hacer q guarde una imagen

Comment: eso lo entendi, a lo que me refiero es a esta parte del código:`var  arrayOfFiles = files[""];

        if (arrayOfFiles.length > 0) {
            var fileNames = [];
            arrayOfFiles.forEach((eachFile) => {
                fileNames.push(eachFile.path)
            });
`

Comment: Mira pues por si ala hora de registrarse el usuario pone una o mas fotos, asi tengo el array para recoger las fotos, estoy aprendiendo  como usar angular y nodejs, si ves una manera mas facil de ingresar una imagen te agradeceria la ayuda la verdad. Pero en principio tengo puesto el array por si hace subidas multiples

Comment: Por cierto quitando todo lo que me daba error, me salta error en path, no entiendo porque , a lo mejor estoy montando un lio para algo tan simple

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado nunca con el modulo 'formidable' para subir archivos pero he estado revisando la Api y la documentación y parece que no es difícil trabajar con el.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que el formulario que pongas en el Front (Angular) para subir los archivos tiene que tener esta configuración:

test.html

```
 <form action="/uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

Ten en cuenta que he modificado el atributo 'action' por el endpoint de express.

A partir de aquí tienes que trabajar con el Back para que gestione los archivos. Te adjunto el código para que puedas probarlo y confírmame si es correcto:

test.js

```
const formidable = require('formidable')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html'); //Formulario de arriba (es para probar)
})

app.post('/uploadImage', (request, response) => {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    const address = path.dirname(__filename).split('/')
    address.pop()

    form.uploadDir = `./imagenes/`; //path donde guardaras la imagines
    form.keepExtensions = true; //mantener las extensiones
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB
    form.multiples = true; //multiples archivos

    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            response.json({
                message: 'error al subir la imagen',
                data: []
            })
        }

        const { upload } = files //Hacemos Destructuring, por lo que equivale a 'const upload = files.upload'
        let data 

        if (upload) { //Si existe archivo subido o no
            let filesPath

            if (Array.isArray(upload)) { //Si se han subido mas de un archivo, es decir, si es un Array de archivos
                filesPath = upload.map(file => file.path) 
            } else {
                filesPath = upload.path
            }

            data = {
                message: 'imagen subida correctamente !!',
                data: filesPath, //Devolvemos una o la lista de rutas de los archivos
                numImagenes: upload.length //Devolvemos la cantidad de archivos
            }
        } else {
            data = {
                message: 'No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ',
                data: [],
                numImagenes: 0
            }
        }

        response.json(data)
    })
    })
   app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server"))
```

Comment: Bueno planta, lo primero mil gracias por esta informacion tan interesante y valiosa que me contestastes, pero desgraciadamente estoy teniendo un problema con la inicializacion de las variables datas y filespath =                                                               

 const data; //variable para la respuesta al Front
              ^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Comment: por lo visto las tengo que inicializar de algun modo esas variables

Comment: Hola @jose angel, ya se por que te aparece ese error, fue culpa mía, declare las variables data y filePath como 'const' cuando deberían de ser 'let'. El motivo es que las constantes no pueden ser instancias mas de una vez, en cambio let si, pudiendo cambiar su valor. Disculpa, no me di cuenta. (lo he editado ademas de corregir otro error)

Comment: Buenas @planta4 , lo primero agradecerte tu dedicacion. Cuando esoy en postman, el servidor manda un codigo 200, eso bien, pero la respuesta en el front es = {
    "message": "No hay ninguna imagen seleccionada para subir .. ",
    "data": [],
    "numImagenes": 0
} ,

Comment: luego compruebo la carpeta done tnedria q estar las imagenes y no esta

Comment: Muchas gracias por el agradecimiento, no hacia falta ya que estamos para ayudar. Según el mensaje que te llega es porque no le llega en la 'request' la info de la imagen. ¿el formulario lo tienes con las mismas configuraciones que te mostré?

Comment: Es que mira de primeras estoy probandolo con el postman, para ir poquito a poco, una vez  q el postman me da todo correcto me meto en el form q es mas coñazo por asi decirlo. no se si me entiendes, y el postman lo que me devulve es que esta vacio, y le estoy enviandole una file (una imagen) , asi que hay alho q esta fallando pero no lo llego a localizar. Pero en principio estoy en postman, aun no he pasado al form en si de mi componente

Comment: En el objeto 'request' que envias desde el postman le llega la info en el body? vaya que el problema se de configuración de express que le falta añadir el 'body-parser'

Comment: Pues supongo q le esta llegando, aunque si me dice que noy hay imagenes a subir

Comment: una cosa q me he fijado es que la variable  data, en algunos casos la uso como objeto json q sera el response al frontend, y otras veces como variable, igual eso no deberia de ser asi, es decir, e alunos casos pone 'data = {lo que sea}' y otras pone 'response.json({loquesea})' y en este ultimo contiene data a veces, eso me parece bastante raro q sea asi

Comment: @jose angel, te edito mi respuesta con la solución que a mi me funciono. Comentarte que el problema estaba en la variable de entrada 'files', es un objeto que tiene una propiedad 'upload' dónde contiene toda la información. Si debugas podrás ver toda su información. Confírmame que te funciona!

Comment: lo he probado, pero no consigo eso, me dice q esta vacio, en cambiio en la consola del backend en nodejs veo que me sale un codigo  200 , o sea que no ha habido errores, en cambio en el frontend me sigue saliendo que no hay files subidos. Tu lo estas probando con postman ?

Comment: Por otra parte, el form que me has puesto lo que pasa es que yo lo hago de otra manera, es decir, mi boton submit llama a una funcion que contiene un servicio con una peticion ajax q se encarga de todo eso, vamos  q es lo mismo, pero como lo estoy probando ocn postman principalmente hasta q vea q funcione eso no me preocupa, de hecho sigue sin ir. Por el backend me devuelve codigo 200 y en cambio en la respuesta del frontend me dice que no estoy subiendo ficheros

Comment: @joseangel,  he estado probando con Postman y no consigo enviar una petición igual que el formulario, aunque si he podido investigar un poco de como realizarlo desde Angular, y seria creando un 'formData', este objeto te podrías encapsular el archivo y enviarlo al backend. Te mando un link donde lo explica un poco aunque si buscas por internet encontraras muchos ejemplos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData